Static HTML page on landing and then load react app when navigating away
If I have the following nginx config:
 server { listen 80; 
server_name testsite.local; 

location =/ { root /var/www/html/TEST/public/; 
try_files $uri $uri/ /test.html; 
} 

location / { root /var/www/html/TEST/WEBSITE/build/; 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html; } 

location /api { alias /var/www/html/TEST/API/; 
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args; } 

location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* { deny all; } 

location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) { 
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; 
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$; 
include fastcgi_params; 
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root; internal; } 
}


What I am trying to do is when you go to testsite.local it loads that static html file (test.html) and then when you navigate away to any other / it will load the react APP (testsite.local/home - testsite.local/login. - etc)
With the above config, it always seems to skip the "location =/" block and go right into the "location /" - not sure where i am going wrong?  Thank you!
If I modify the above to this:
 `     location =/GETME {
     root /var/www/html/TEST/public/;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /test.html;
  }
 `

and then go to to testsite.local/GETME it works as expected, but I want it to go to it at testsite.local and then everywhere outside of that load the react app.
Thanks for the help!
